# Invalid vagrant options

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, provisioning, vagrant-provision

I use vagrant. I want to modify the provisioning behaviour when I restore a vagrant snapshot. According to [this web page](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html#_no_provision), I should be able to use the option

```
--[no-]provision
```

When I try to run this option though, my vagrant complains that I provided an invalid argument. When I check the version, it says I am using the latest version.

```
$ vagrant snapshot list
my_snapshot1
my_snapshot2

$ vagrant snapshot restore --no-provision my_snapshot2
An invalid option was specified. The help for this command
is available below.

Usage: vagrant snapshot restore [options] [vm-name] <name>

Restore a snapshot taken previously with snapshot save.
    -h, --help                       Print this help

$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.8.1
```

What am I doing wrong? When I run it without that option, it restores the snapshot just fine. Tried also changing the order of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6752) which has been [fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/6879) to allow the `--no-provision` option when running `vagrant restore`

This is coming in the next release of vagrant, but you can build also from github as this has been merged into core.